# How long does the gear extension/retraction takes on the ATR-42?

Tags: aircraft-systems, landing-gear, atr-42

Which is typical time of landing gear extension in normal conditions ? I would like to know it especially for the ATR-42 but any other typical value is welcome ! 
Furthermore can you provide any link to data sheet for ATR-42 technical data about landing gear ?

Comment: You mean as in how long it takes for the gear to go from the up position to full down all green & vice versa?

Comment: Yes please ! That's the right question !

Answer (score 1):

In [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKw3NlfyWe0) showing landing gear maintenance operations on an ATR42, I'd say about **11 seconds** for both extension and retraction.

A more precise timing could be gathered from an uninterrupted cockpit video, measuring from gear lever action action to "three green" on.